# MS CRM 2011 Outlook Client New Record button doesn't always work

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, outlook-addin, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have MS Outlook 2007, the MS CRM 2011 Outlook client and MS CRM 2011 on-premise.

After you install the MS CRM 2011 Outlook client you have a new toolbar within Outlook 2007.  On that Toolbar is a button for 'New Record.'  If you click that button a dropdown appears with different options, which for me includes 'Account' and 'Contact.'

The first time I click on 'Account' a small popup opens with a message like 'waiting for web page to load'  No form ever appears.  clicking on the button subsequent times produces the same result, minus the 'waiting' popup.  I cannot seem to get the CRM form to appear.

The interesting part is that when the 'New Record' > 'Contact' option is clicked the Contact form appears and works without issue.

A work around for this is to use the actual website.  That works without issue.  However, I have a lot of users who use Outlook.  So getting this to work proper would be ideal.

I did notice that an iisreset solved the issue once, but that doesn't solve the issue permanently or consistently.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it works with Account and not with Contact is interesting as it means that the connector is talking successcully to CRM. Security roles should be fine if you can do it through the web interface also.

And that the issue was solved through an IIS reset temporarily points more towards connection issues, or possibly something on the Account form which is causing it to not load through the outlook client correctly.

Also check that you have Outlook 2007 with service pack 2 installed. Thats the minimum requirement for using the 2011 Offfice Outlook client.

Comment: Double checked the version and we are running Outlook 2007 SP2.  Will look into connection issues.  We did restart IIS and Accounts magically worked again.